Holomorphic map with no singular values is a covering map?
I am working on Problem 8-c from Milnor's Dynamics in One Complex Variable, which describes a necessary and sufficient condition for a holomorphic map $f : S \to S'$ between Riemann surfaces to be a covering map. In particular, we define singular values of $f$ to be points $v\in S'$ that are either critical (i.e., there exists a $p\in f^{-1}(\{v\})$ such that the differential $df_p : T_pS \to T_vS'$ is non-surjective) or asymptotic (i.e., there exists a continuous curve $c : [0,1) \to S$ which eventually escapes any compact subset, such that $\lim_{t\to1^-} f(c(t)) = v$) for $f$. The problem asks us to prove

A simply connected open set $U\subseteq S'$ is evenly covered by $f$ (meaning $f$ bijectively takes each connected component of $f^{-1}(U)$ to $U$) if and only if $U$ contains no singular values of $f$. (I believe you also have to add the criterion that $U\cap f(S)$ is nonempty.)

I've proved the $(\implies)$ direction already, but I'm having trouble with $(\impliedby)$. According to the Goldberg and Keen reference that Milnor gives in the exercise, the proof follows by applying analytic continuation to $f^{-1}$ to all of $U$, beginning from some open neighborhood of a point $u_0\in U\cap f(S)$. Continuation is possible along curves in $U$ since no point therein is a critical value of $f$ (apply Inverse Function Theorem), and so we can extend to $U$ by the Monodromy Theorem since $U$ is simply connected.
The above argument seems to rely on $U$ being contained in the image of $f$. I think this is where the "no asymptotic values" hypothesis comes in, but this is where I'm stuck. Here is my attempt so far: suppose for contradiction that there exists a $u\in U\setminus f(S)$. Pick any $u_0\in U\cap f(S)$, and draw a continuous path $c : [0,1] \to U$ from $u$ to $u_0$. Fix $t^* = \inf \ c^{-1}(U\setminus f(S))$, which is well-defined and in $[0,1]$ since $1 \in c^{-1}(U\setminus f(S))$.
I claim that $t^*\in c^{-1}(U\setminus f(S))$. If not, then there would exist a $p\in S$ such that $f(p) = c(t^*)$. Since $p$ is not a critical point of $f$, the Inverse Function Theorem applies to say there exist connected open sets $V\subseteq S$ and $V' \subseteq S'$ such that $p\in V$, $c(t^*)\in V'$, and $f|_V : V\to V'$ is a biholomorphism. By continuity of $c$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|t-t^*| < \delta$ implies $c(t)\in V' \cap U \subseteq f(S)$. But now we see $[0, t^*+\delta) \subseteq c^{-1}(U\cap f(S))$. This contradicts that $t^*$ is the infimum; it must be that $t^*\in c^{-1}(U\setminus f(S))$ in actuality.
Now I suspect that $c(t^*)$ would have to be an asymptotic value of $f$ (which would be our final contradiction). My intuition is that $c|_{[0,t^*)}$ should lift via $f$ to a path in $S$ which eventually escapes any compact subset. I know at least that $c([0,t^*)) \subseteq f(S)$ by definition of $t^*$, but I can't seem to proceed further. Any help is appreciated!

Are you sure you stated the problem correctly? As written, it is simply false. The correct statement is that a surjective map without critical values is a covering map. More generally, a surjective local homeomorphism satisfying the path-lifting property is a covering map.

@MoisheKohan I believe it's stated correctly (see that "no asymptotic points" assumption)

Oh, ok, I missed the "simply connected" assumption.
